# How would I make the camera not rotate as the player rotates?

Tags: java, lwjgl

Right now, whenever my player turns, the camera turns with it.  This was intentional, but I changed my mind on that feature when I inputted other camera controls, and right now, I can't seem to disable that functionality without breaking the whole camera system.  I'm working with OpenGL and LWJGL, but I don't think knowledge in those will be too necessary for this.  I basically want the camera not to turn as the player does.  Thank you for your time, and have a

Here is the camera class:

```
package entities;

import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

public class Camera {
private float distanceFromPlayer = 50;
private float angleAroundPlayer = 0;

private Vector3f position = new Vector3f(10,20,10);
private float pitch = 45;
private float yaw;
private float roll;

private Player player;

public Camera(Player player){
    this.player = player;
}

public void move(){
    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LEFT)){
        angleAroundPlayer -= 1;
    }
    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_RIGHT)){
        angleAroundPlayer += 1;
    }

    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_UP)){
        pitch += 1;
    }

    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_DOWN)){
        pitch -= 1;
    }

    float horizontalDistance = calculateHorizontalDistance();
    float verticalDistance = calculateVerticalDistance();
    calculateCameraPosition(horizontalDistance,verticalDistance);
    this.yaw = 180 - (player.getRotY() + angleAroundPlayer);
}

public Vector3f getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public float getPitch() {
    return pitch;
}

public float getYaw() {
    return yaw;
}

public float getRoll() {
    return roll;
}

private float calculateHorizontalDistance(){
    return (float)(distanceFromPlayer * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(pitch)));
}

private float calculateVerticalDistance(){
    return (float)(distanceFromPlayer * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(pitch)));
}

private void calculateCameraPosition(float horizontalDistance, float verticalDistance){
    float theta = player.getRotY() + angleAroundPlayer;
    float offsetX = (float)(horizontalDistance * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(theta)));
    float offsetZ = (float)(horizontalDistance * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta)));
    position.x = player.getPosition().x - offsetX;
    position.z = player.getPosition().z - offsetZ;
    position.y = player.getPosition().y + verticalDistance;
}
}
```

And here is the player class:
package entities;

```
import models.TexturedModel;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;
import renderEngine.DisplayManager;

public class Player extends Entity{

private static final float RUN_SPEED = 20;
private static final float TURN_SPEED = 180;
private static final float GRAVITY = -50;
private static final float JUMP_POWER = 40;
private static final float TERRAIN_HEIGHT = 0.5f;

private float currentSpeed = 0;
private float currentTurnSpeed = 0;
private float upwardsSpeed = 0;

private boolean isInAir = false;

public Player(TexturedModel model, Vector3f position, float rotX, float rotY, float rotZ, float scale) {
    super(model, position, rotX, rotY, rotZ, scale);
}

public void move(){
    checkInputs();super.increaseRotation(0,currentTurnSpeed * DisplayManager.getFrameTimeSeconds(),0);
    float distance = currentSpeed * DisplayManager.getFrameTimeSeconds();
    float dx = (float) (distance * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(super.getRotY())));
    float dz = (float) (distance * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(super.getRotY())));
    super.increasePosition(dx,0,dz);
    upwardsSpeed += GRAVITY * DisplayManager.getFrameTimeSeconds();
    super.increasePosition(0,upwardsSpeed * DisplayManager.getFrameTimeSeconds(),0);
    if(super.getPosition().y < TERRAIN_HEIGHT){
        upwardsSpeed =0;
        isInAir = false;
        super.getPosition().y = TERRAIN_HEIGHT;
    }
}

private void jump(){
    if(!isInAir){
        this.upwardsSpeed = JUMP_POWER;
        isInAir = true;
    }
}

private void checkInputs(){
    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W)){
        this.currentSpeed = RUN_SPEED;
    }
    else if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S)) {
        this.currentSpeed = -RUN_SPEED;
    }
    else{
        this.currentSpeed = 0;
    }

    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)){
        this.currentTurnSpeed = -TURN_SPEED;
    }

    else if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)){
        this.currentTurnSpeed = TURN_SPEED;
    }

    else{
        this.currentTurnSpeed = 0;
    }

    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE)){
        jump();
    }
}
}
```

And if needed, here is the Entity Class:
package entities;

```
import models.TexturedModel;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

public class Entity {
private TexturedModel model;
private Vector3f position;
private float rotX,rotY,rotZ;
private float scale;

public Entity(TexturedModel model, Vector3f position, float rotX, float rotY, float rotZ,float scale){
    this.model = model;
    this.position = position;
    this.rotX = rotX;
    this.rotY = rotY;
    this.rotZ = rotZ;
    this.scale = scale;
}

public void increasePosition(float dx, float dy, float dz){
    this.position.x += dx;
    this.position.y += dy;
    this.position.z += dz;
}

public void increaseRotation(float dx, float dy, float dz){
    this.rotX += dx;
    this.rotY += dy;
    this.rotZ += dz;
}

public TexturedModel getModel() {
    return model;
}

public Vector3f getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public float getRotX() {
    return rotX;
}

public float getRotY() {
    return rotY;
}

public float getRotZ() {
    return rotZ;
}

public float getScale() {
    return scale;
}

public void setModel(TexturedModel model) {
    this.model = model;
}

public void setPosition(Vector3f position) {
    this.position = position;
}

public void setRotX(float rotX) {
    this.rotX = rotX;
}

public void setRotY(float rotY) {
    this.rotY = rotY;
}

public void setRotZ(float rotZ) {
    this.rotZ = rotZ;
}

public void setScale(float scale) {
    this.scale = scale;
}
}
```